# Nvidia GeForce GTX 960 Displayport black screen for a few seconds

Tags: windows-10, displayport

I have a MSI Nvidia GeForce GTX  960 2GB graphics card and whenever I turn on my computer, I get a "no signal" on my monitor for a few seconds when Windows finished loading and is logging in. I'm using the Displayport to HDMI, using the right cable. Furthermore, whenever I enter or leave fullscreen games or videoes, it goes black for 5~8 seconds (depending on video or game).
The issue started in Windows 7, and persisted when I upgraded to Windows 10. After some update (I can't remember which) the issue was gone. Now it's back, only thing that has changed is the driver version and some windows updates.

I've tried uninstallng using DDU and re-install latest driver, but without any luck solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

I would try programme called DriverBooster 4. It will update all of your drivers. It helped my friend with a similar problem. I am not sure if it will help you but it's free so it's worth a try.

Comment: I've tried Driver Booster as suggested, but sadly, it doesn't help. After I uninstalled the graphics driver, DB installed the driver again (same version), and the problem was still there